# How sharepoint url is made using some parameters..confused?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007

I have read a lot of blogs and is confused about some certain things while creating share point application.

I have read a blog which says your URL should have :

https://.//

How would I know what is my app prefix and how to create  app id and host web relative service are given.

please let me know how can we give them in central administrator. I am trying to give these on central administrator..please let me know.. Thanks in advance,if any link and tutorial will help me seriously.Thankyou

Comment: Honestly.. I am confused after reading your question.. But you ask 'how to create app id' ans is http://<SharePointWebsite>/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx   details can be found here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj687469.aspx

Comment: I am agree with Vaibhav, Can you elaborate question ?

Comment: Actually I have made a DNS on which App will open when you download it but when app opens url which should come is not coming with that i am not able to get the app prefix and app id. I have already wrote the app prefix in central admin  -->apps-->configure URL && I have also generated the app client and secret id and  placed it in successfully in web config file and app manifest file.But its not coming in URL when i opening my app in share point environment. By the way I am making an app in  provider hosted environment and its is working on intranet in organization.